# How to use comma separated variable?

Tags: python

I have a variable like this: ignore = val1,val2

But it's unclear for me how to use these values as separate ones.

Currently (with my knowledge) i need to hard code them like code below:

```
if (not Path.find("val1") > -1 ) and (not Path.find("val2") > -1 ):
    etc
```

Now i want test added to it, and again i need to hard code it like this:

```
if (not Path.find("val1") > -1 ) and (not Path.find("val2") > -1 ) and (not Path.find("test") > -1 ):
```

Isn't there a better way of doing this?

Comment: could you provide more details on what `Path` is and what `Path.find` does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `ignore` is a tuple of value names:

```
if all(Path.find(v) <= -1 for v in ignore):
```

This has the advantage to stop as soon as the first condition is false. Just like your hard-coded example.

Comment: +1, but I would prefer `if all(Path.find(v) <= -1 for v in ignore)`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker - I like it too.

Comment: Thanks for helping. After reading for a few hours on tuples i understand the process. What i don't understand is when i have a tuple like this ignore = val1, val2 it doesn't match any values but when i make it like this ignore = val1 it works perfect. For some reason i can't get multiple values in this tuple. I guess i need to read a bit more.

Answer (score 3):

This is a `tuple`, one of the basic datatypes in Python.

You can access the different values using indexing notation, like `ignore[0]`, `ignore[1]`, etc.

However, if you're struggling with fundamental language features like this, I'd strongly recommend that you go read a Python tutorial before continuing.

Comment: `any/all` can be found in the tutorial. But one has to get the idea to use them here.

Answer (score 0):

`ignore = var1, var2` essentially assigns `ignore` to a tuple, holding the values of `var1` and `var2`. To access them, use `ignore[0]` or `ignore[1]` for the first and second elements respectively (in Python list/tuple indices start at 0, not 1).

Aside from this, you could also use `collections.namedtuple`. This allows you to treat the tuple like a class with attributes:

```
import collections
sometuple = collections.namedtuple('sometuple', 'var1 var2')
```

You can then access the element by name:

```
ignore = sometuple(var1, var2)
ignore.var1  # first element
ignore.var2  # second element
```

See the documentation for `namedtuples` [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).

For general information on `tuples`, see [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).